# Using WebViews With Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uiwebview

Recently in my app I have been using Firebase to store information for my app and it has worked well. Now I am using it to stream videos with a web view being used in the tableview to display Youtube videos.  When trying to link the WebView to the database, I get an error that says:

> Type 'video' has no subscript members

What would be causing this?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

class videoController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var ref = DatabaseReference()
    var video = [UIWebView]()
    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle = 0

    @IBOutlet var videoController: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref.child("Videos").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let post = snapshot.value as? UIWebView
            if let actualPost = post {
                self.video.append(actualPost)
                self.videoController.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return video.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let video = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "video") as! video
        video.videos.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = video[indexPath.row]

        return(video)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does **let post = snapshot.value as? UIWebView** firebase return webviews ???!!!!!! =D

Comment: I'm not sure. Normally I use labels to display text, so I switched it to WebView to display the video, with the video url in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let video = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "video") as! video
```

is your problem. This creates a new, local variable named `video` and it hides your `video` array property. Change it to:

```
let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "video") as! video
```

Here's the whole method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "video") as! video
    videoCell.videos.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = video[indexPath.row]

    return videoCell
}
```

But on top of all of that, why do you have an array of web views? You certainly are not getting web views from Firebase.

And please fix your naming conventions. Class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase letters. Variable, function, and case names start with lowercase letters. And use descriptive names. Naming everything simply `video` is confusing.

And change your `video` array to `videos`.